# Особенности перемещения файлов с помощью mv в Linux

Tags: linux, файлы, запись

Почему при перемещении файла, в который идет запись, на тот же носитель, эта операция происходит успешно. Однако, если попытаться такой файл перемести на другой материальный носитель, то новый файл оказывается пустым. Почему это происходит?

Comment: Видимо потому, что писатель в момент `mv` еще не сбросил (`write()`) свой буфер в файл. Иначе какие-то данные скопировалиь бы. А вот вся остальная запись пропадет, поскольку писатель будет продолжать писать в уже удаленный файл (который реально пропадет, когда последний писатель (если их в момент `mv` было несколько) закроет файл)

Answer (score 5):

В пределах одной файловой системы переносится только элемент каталога указывающий на *инод* содержащий файл. А после открытия файла для записи по факту вся работа идет с *инодом* и спокойно продолжается вне зависимости от того сколько указателей каталогов на него существует (может даже 0 - файл удален). А при переносе на другую ФС требуется перенести еще и данные и в зависимости от того как именно был открыт файл и проходит запись, данные для чтения и переноса могут быть еще не доступны. Кроме того, при переносе на другую ФС, даже если какие то данные были доступны и были перенесены, то все равно новые данные туда никак не попадут, т.к. на изначальной ФС запись каталога удалена, но запись продолжается в удаленный файл.